# parseFloat does not return accurate value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I have an application which read API return string from a website and compare it to a value to see if it is greater or equal to particular float, the API return two float String which is `"2366.5876"` and `"4067.4076"` which when we add up equal to `6433.9952`

But what I tried on Javascript provide different result:

```
cumulative = 0;
cumulative += parseFloat("2366.5876")
cumulative += parseFloat("4067.4076")
//here it return 6433.995199999999 instead of 6433.9952 . Why??
```

which when I compare to `6433.9952` , produce false which is not intended

```
cumulative >= 6433.9952 //False ???
```

Can I know how can I solve this??

Comment: `parseFloat` is fine. It's the addition of floats that produces a different number.

Comment: @VLAZ Do you know why it perform so? Any way that we could get the correct value?

Comment: There is a linked dupe. Here are more resources: https://0.30000000000000004.com/ | [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) | [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/) | [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633)

Comment: Consider that between 6433.9951 and 6433.9952 are infinite real numbers, and yet your computer has finite memory.  You're going to have to approximate at some point.

Comment: @James that's misleading as these two numbers *aren't* infinite. Not when in decimal. The problem is that the binary representation of them is imprecise and performing mathematical operations with imprecise numbers leads to a cumulative error.

Comment: @VLAZ The numbers are indeed finite but there is an infinity of other finite numbers between them.  It would be impossible for a computer to assign a different representation to each of them.